# Creating a Sample of Random Points with an output of LAT/LON

Tags: r, tidyverse, gis, r-sf

I'm doing an analysis and want to create a random sample of points within a polygon and then extract the Lat/LON of those points so I can use another package with them.

So far I've been able to create a random number of points using this chuck of code

```r
points = sf::st_sample(counties, size=60)

random_points <- points %>% 
  sf::st_coordinates() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

but I'm unable to the convert the point geometry into a LAT/LON.

Any thoughts on how I might go about that?

Comment: So what do you get instead? Is it just about column names ( X / Y  vs lon/ lat) )or projected coordinates (e.g. UTM) ?

Comment: It just gives me the geometry point but I'm looking for a lat/lon so I can feed it into gmapsdistance package

Comment: Please include a small subset from your `points` , e.g. output from `dput(points[1:3])`

Comment: `#          X        Y
# 1  685932.4     4295277
# 2  457802.7     4335224
# 3  487106.7     4222119`

I'm having trouble formatting it but these are the output I get back. I'm not sure if it helps but the state I'm looking at is WV

Comment: Well, that's not from `points` nor from `dput()` ,. You can still edit your question and all additional details should end up in the question itself, there you can also format it properly. Anyway, for geographic coordinates you need to transform your points to WGS84. Try with  `points %>% st_transform("WGS84") %>% st_coordinates()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `sf::st_coordinates()` it will output a matrix, which you then can (but don't *have* to) convert to a data frame.

It will have columns named X and Y, the context of which will depend on the original CRS (if you feed it with data in WGS84 this will be long - lat, but a projected CRS will give you eastings & northings).

Also be careful when interpreting it for (multi) lines & polygons. Points are easy...

For an example in action consider this piece of code; what it does is:

- creates a sampling area from the well known & much loved North Carolina shapefile
- draws a sample of 5 points there
- creates a data frame of coordinates
- draws a plot to visually check
- saves the coordiantes to object called `points_as_coordinates`

```r
library(sf) 
library(dplyr)

# a shapefile, any shapefile...
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise()

# some samples (not too many, thank you) to play with
sample_points <- st_sample(nc, 5)

plot(nc)
plot(sample_points, pch = 4, col = "red", add = T)
```

[image]

```r
# here be the action!
points_as_coordinates <- st_coordinates(sample_points) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
  
points_as_coordinates
#          X        Y
# 1 -81.38738 35.97074
# 2 -77.12273 36.10250
# 3 -77.00998 34.94525
# 4 -78.65373 35.51981
# 5 -76.73266 35.93567
```

Comment: I'm not really sure this code worked for me. It looks like the LAT/LON are in the antarctic. When I check your X and Y it gives me back a point in antarctica

Comment: @Blue_Wolverine These would all be in the Antarctic if you had latitude and longitude mixed up. X is longitude, Y is latitude.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. I simply want to take a point geometry and convert it to LAT/LON is there no simple way to do that?

Comment: I often mix lang and long - but I don't think I have this time. X coord is longitude, Y latitude. Compare this with reference values for Raleigh NC, which is known to be at longitude -78.6381 (negative = west of Greenwich) and latitude 35.7795 (positive = north of Equator).

Comment: yes your code works, I'm just saying when I try to reproduce it with my data I dont get an output with a lat/lon that doesnt make sense